# How to dual wield as a hexblade warlock

Tags: dnd-5e, hexblade

If I want to dual-wield as a Hexblade warlock, is there a way I can add my charisma to both attacks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need Pact of the Blade.

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch one weapon […]. When you attack with that weapon, you can use your Charisma modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, for the attack and damage rolls. […] **If you later gain the Pact of the Blade feature, this benefit extends to every pact weapon you conjure with that feature, no matter the weapon's type.**

<sup>(*Xanathar’s Guide to Everything*, pg. 55-56, **emphasis** mine)</sup>

Hexblade allows you to use Charisma for attacks with one weapon you choose, **plus** with any pact weapon you have. So you can have two separate weapons: your pact weapon, plus your Hexblade-chosen weapon.

Note that any invocations or whatever talking about your pact weapon refer only to the one that is chosen with Pact of the Blade, **not** the other weapon chosen with Hexblade.

Finally, when you make an offhand attack, you do not, by default, add your ability modifier to your damage. So for the offhand attack, you’ll use Charisma on the attack roll, but nothing on the damage roll. You can fix that with the Two-Weapon Fighting style, which you can get by multiclassing or the Fighting Initiate feat.